# sql use while loop to fetch values and run query on them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have long query which is ran based on two value parameters (contcode, datime).
I am using this while loop to fetch these values in order from another table, run the query and insert the result into a final table:

```
    DECLARE @r TABLE (id int IDENTITY (1,1),lnr char (9), pday datetime)
    INSERT INTO @r (lnr, pday)
    SELECT TOP 1 lnr, pday FROM memrepay

    DECLARE @counter int SET @counter = 1
    DECLARE @contcode char (9) 
    DECLARE @datime datetime


    WHILE @counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @r)
    BEGIN


              --long query


    END

        SET @counter = @counter + 1 

    END

    SELECT * FROM @finaltable
```

However long query only works when I fetch 1 row:

```
   SELECT TOP 1 contcode, datime FROM @tbl
```

And if I don't use TOP 1, I get the error message of:

```
  "Subquery returned more than 1 value...."
```

How can I fetch those two or more values in order, run the long query based each , not getting this error?

Comment: I think you should join your table for codes `SELECT code, datime FROM @tbl where ...` with your long query by Code.

Comment: best is to change the inner query to process a set of code & datime instead of 1 at a time. Can you also show us how the "long query" looks like ?

Comment: @Squirrel  thanks, I will try changing long query to process a set of codes...

Comment: @Max can you explain more

Comment: you must solve your current script.show us your long query.Over all your approach is wrong.while loop is not require.Check why your long query return more than 1 record without using top.

Comment: @Squirrel  I just update query adding that long query...I am sure you all find it too complicated...@KumarHarsh

Comment: One comment, when working with database, you need to think in-terms of `SET BASE` and not row by row. I will try to take a look at your query when i am bored :)

Comment: Here the goal is to find out how much of total payment a client has made has gone to principle amount and how much to interest. So, once I calculated total amount before that particular payment, and then all of it. Finally, I compare both ledgers deducting values in ledger2 from ledger1 it gives values i want. Also, i 've done some extra calculation to find the payment amount has been applied to which installment(s).

Comment: @Squirrel yeah, I know it's horrible...but it gives me the result - but for one!

Comment: at the end of query there is a `tablesinlongquery`, I can't find any reference to that table earlier

Comment: @sqluser for example you have code to insert `INSERT INTO @repayevents (lnr, tcode, pday, mprinc, mint, mcomm,totalpaid)
            SELECT memrepay.lnr, memrepay.tcode, memrepay.pday, memrepay.mprinc, memrepay.mint, memrepay.mcomm, memrepay.mprinc+memrepay.mint FROM memrepay 
            INNER JOIN repay ON memrepay.tcode = repay.tcode AND memrepay.lnr = repay.lnr
            WHERE memrepay.lnr = @contcode ORDER BY pday` so instead of using `WHERE memrepay.lnr = @contcode` use `inner join (SELECT t.lnr FROM @r as t WHERE t.id = @counter) t on ...`

Comment: @Squirrel by **tablesinlongquery** I mean selecting from **tcode**, **receiptsm1**, **receiptsm2** and **smactive** tables

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move the `SET @counter = @counter + 1` up between the `BEGIN...END` block under your `WHILE` loop. That's probably why it only works for TOP 1, since 1 is <= COUNT(*).

```
DECLARE @r TABLE (id int IDENTITY (1,1),lnr char (9), pday datetime)
    INSERT INTO @r (lnr, pday)
    SELECT TOP 1 lnr, pday FROM memrepay

    DECLARE @counter int SET @counter = 1
    DECLARE @contcode char (9) 
    DECLARE @datime datetime


    WHILE @counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @r)
    BEGIN


              --long query

        SET @counter = @counter + 1 

    END   

    END

    SELECT * FROM @finaltable
```

Comment: ...aaand just realized this question is over 2 years old. How did I get here. Hope you figured it out...